# How to call setState in a widget to change that widget with other one?

Tags: flutter

I have 2 widget and I put the first one into a variable. When I click a button in the first widget, I will call setState and put the second widget to the variable to rebuild. However, it didn't work.

I try to call setState in the parent widget of them and it work. Anyone know what wrong with it and how to solve this?

This is my code:

```
Widget checkinWidget = CheckInTemplate();
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: checkinWidget
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

I put the first widget CheckInTemplate to a variable and in CheckInTemplate, I have a button:

```
RaisedButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 60),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                checkinWidget = CaptureCameraTemplate();
              });
            },
            child: Text('Check in',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'
              ),),
          ),
```

When I click the button, nothing happen.

Comment: Please, share some code.

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv sorry my bad, I have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed one example for this, kindly check the below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: WidgetHandling(),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetHandling extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WidgetHandling();
  }
}

class _WidgetHandling extends State<WidgetHandling> {

  Widget widgetHolder;

  void initState() {
    widgetHolder = firstWidget();
    super.initState();
  }

   Widget firstWidget() {
     return Container(
       color: Colors.white,
       child: Center(
         child: FlatButton(
           color: Colors.blue,
           textColor: Colors.white,
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
           onPressed: () {
             setState(() {
               widgetHolder = secondWidget();
             });
           },
           child: Text(
             "First Widget",
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }

      Widget secondWidget() {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
               setState(() {
                 widgetHolder = firstWidget();
               });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Second Widget",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return widgetHolder;
     }
   }
```

Comment: You make me realized that I put 2 widget in 2 class and when I call setState, it only rebuild the class of the first widget but not the parent widget. Thanks you it work now.

Answer (score 1):

You might have added this line,

```
Widget checkinWidget = CheckInTemplate();
```

in `build` method.

Remove it from `build` method and put to out side of build and then it will work.

Comment: Sorry it my mistake, I put the first and the second widget into 2 class so when I call setState, it will rebuild that class but not the parent widget of them. Thank for helping me.